# Is multiclass StyleGAN2+ADA training affected by inbalanced dataset?

Tags: python, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to train StyleGAN2+Ada (default Nvidia PyTorch implementation) with multiclass dataset. Overall all images in the dataset are very similar to each other with minor differences.

Amount of images per class:

- Class A: 3142
- Class B: 7304
- Class C: 2883
- Class D: 1164

Does it affect training quality or should I balance dataset by reducing images amount for classes A, B and C to 1164?

Answer (score 0):

If you reduce images amount for any class this will lead to that your trained model will draw worse this class. If the classes differ very slightly, then these photos should be enough. From my experience about 1000 photos are enough for the model to learn new class that's differ very slightly from others.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).